# Is there a limit on how many files I can store in s3?

Tags: filesystems, amazon-s3, limits

I did not see any information about this else where, and I want to assume amazon is doing some creative here. I am pretty sure at least with some file systems there are limits on how many files can be in a single folder. For s3 this would mean objects within folders within buckets?

Are there any limits placed on the amount of objects or the amount of folders?

I know there are file size limits and items returned per request limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are **no limits** to the number of files/folders you can place in a bucket.

You are however limited to 100 buckets per account.

Comment: 100 buckets per account. You can make as many accounts as you need, it would seem.

Comment: @Tom - Thanks, I've clarified my answer although it would be pretty inconvenient to manage if you had lots of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There really are no folders in S3. Its a key (like a path) - value (the data) store. Folders are created by using '/' characters in the keys, and so are just a convention.

Keep in mind that if you want enumerate through all your millions of keys in a single folder, it may take a while! So if there any restrictions they are on your end - users don't generally like a list of 100000 files in a single folder.

Comment: you can use the `prefix` and `delimiter` parameters to make finding and listing objects easier. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?ListingKeysHierarchy.html. However, the best option is to 'index' your S3 buckets in a database somewhere and use that to search your S3 assets.